# rpc function tell me to reload the schema cache

Tags: sql, postgresql, supabase, create-function

I am creating an rpc function to get the number of likes for each post for a user, so I have created a function that takes userId as an argument, which is the uuid of the user that is in the session. But when I call the function on the front it returns me.

> If a new function was created in the database with this name and parameters, try reloading the schema cache.

The function:

```
create function get_number_of_posts_by_user(userId uuid)
returns integer
as $$
  SELECT 
  count(pl.id)
  FROM 
  auth.users au
  join posts p on p.user_id = au.id
  join post_likes pl on pl.post_id = p.id
  where au.id = userId
$$ language sql;
```

Comment: Hey Ricardo. Have you tried to change the parameter type to `create function get_number_of_posts_by_user(user_id text)` then, on the where:  `where au.id::text = user_id`?

Comment: Hello @Mansueli my mistake was at the parameter that i used (it should not be writen in capital letter unles you use "variable")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> get the number of likes for each post for a user

You need to group by post to get there.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_likes_per_post_for_user(_userid uuid)
  RETURNS TABLE (post_id uuid, likes bigint)  -- use actual type of post_id
  LANGUAGE sql AS
$func$
SELECT p.id, count(*)
FROM   posts      p 
JOIN   post_likes pl ON pl.post_id = p.id
WHERE  p.user_id = _userid
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;  -- or some other order?
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM get_likes_per_post_for_user(<some_uuid>);
```

Major points:

- You don't need to involve the table `users` at all. Filter by `posts.user_id` directly. Cheaper.
- `count(*)` >> `count(pl.id)` in this case. A bit cheaper, too. [count(*) has a separate implementation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) in Postgres.
- `count()` returns `bigint`, not `integer`. Match what `RETURNS` declares one way or the other.
- Avoid naming conflicts between function parameters and table columns. Prefixing `_` for parameters (and never using the same for column names) is one common convention.
  And table-qualify column names. In this case to avoid a conflict between the `OUT` parameter `post_id` (also visible in the query) and `post_likes.post_id`.
- When counting the number of likes, don't call your function "get_number_of_posts...".

Your original issue may have been a XY problem that goes away with a proper function definition.

#### Addressing the title

If you actually need to reload the schema cache, use:

```
SELECT pg_stat_clear_snapshot();
```

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-STATS-VIEWS)

> You can invoke `pg_stat_clear_snapshot()` to discard the current
> transaction's statistics snapshot or cached values (if any). The next
> use of statistical information will (when in snapshot mode) cause a
> new snapshot to be built or (when in cache mode) accessed statistics
> to be cached.

I have never had a need for this myself, yet. Typically, the problem lies elsewhere.